# Java validation of object with annotation directly

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

The conventional way of java validation is to define a class with properties and annotated with one or many validation constraint annotations such as `@NotNull` or `@Future`.

Is it possible to validate an object directly with validator constraint annotation without specifying a class. For example:

```
String a = "";
validator.validate(a, javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's clearly not a use case for which Hibernate Validator has been designed.

What you would have to do is to create a `ConstraintValidator` from the constraint and the type of the object and then use the `isValid()` method. The entry point would be `ConstraintValidatorManager`.

It's an internal class so it's subject to change without warning, even in a micro version so I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: I am developing a simple EAV module which needs to validate each of the attribute during runtime without defining a java class. is there any hibernate validator internal classes that able to call for this purpose?

Comment: I able to create the annotation class instance via java reflection and able to set all the annotation properties during runtime.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide more information. But really, it's not something you should do. Note that you can validate a given property of a bean with `Validator#validateProperty()` or even `Validator#validateValue()`